# Remove rows matching vector

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I have a dataframe with 12 column and 4225 rows.

One of the column is id and contains number.

I would like to remove some rows based on a vector.

`id_to_remove <- c(2721,3893, 3904, 3905, 3907, 3908, 3909, 3910, 3912)`

I tried many solutions but I somehow can't make it work such as

`data <- data[!data$id == 2721| 3893|3904| 3905| 3907| 3908| 3909| 3910| 3912]`

Any idea?

Comment: `data[!(data$id %in% id_to_remove)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
#Code
data <- data[!data$id %in% id_to_remove,]
```

Comment: YES! Gosh I lost so much time on that one.
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution using the `dplyr` package. Use `filter` with `%in%` to subset the data according to the values in the `id_to_remove` vector.

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)


id_to_remove <- c(2721, 3893, 3904, 3905, 3907, 3908, 3909, 3910, 3912)

data <- tibble(
  id = c(2721, 3893, 3904, 3905, 3907, 3908, 3909, 3910, 3912, 1234, 4567, 1234, 6567, 8765, 5678),
  foo = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
)

data %>% 
  filter(!(id %in% id_to_remove))

#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>      id   foo
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  1234    10
#> 2  4567    11
#> 3  1234    12
#> 4  6567    13
#> 5  8765    14
#> 6  5678    15
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>